# Como añadir nuevo código latex en mi html sin la necesidad de crear una nueva línea y centrando el latex?

Tags: html, css, depuración, latex

Como añadir nuevo código latex en mi html sin la necesidad de crear una nueva línea y centrando el latex?

Lo que me refiere se puede ver en esta imagen cortada:

[image: El problema]

Y solo quiero tener el latex "f:A->B" en la misma línea que la anterior sin necesidad de centrarla y crear una nueva línea.

El código es:

```
<html>
<head>
</html>
<meta name="author" content="Iván Camacho"/>
<meta charset="UTF-8" content="Iván Camacho"/>
<meta name="author" content="Iván Camacho"/>
<meta name="author" content="Iván Camacho"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS Matemáticas.css">
<style>   
body{
    background-image: url(http://tuderechoasaber.com.do/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/blockchain.gif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" async="" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.4/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML">
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="contenedor">
<div class="Negro4">
<img src="Fondo_Negro - copia.jpg" width="1700" height="2000">
</div>
<div class="texto-encima"> <center>
<div class="TÍTULO"> <u style="color:aliceblue"> <p style="color:aliceblue"> INTRODUCCIÓN AL CÁLCULO </p> </u> </div>
<p style="color:aliceblue"> </br> Para poder hablar de cálculo, nos tenemos que remontar a la definición de relaciones y funciones.
</br> Es importante conocer que una función es una maquina que transforma </br> valores de <i>x</i> pertenecientes al dominio A, a valores de
<i>y</i> pertenecientes al rango, B. </p>
<div class="mathdisplay1"> <p><span class="mathdisplay1" style="color:aliceblue">\[ f: A\to B \]</span></p> </div>
</center> </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ya está. Necesito ayuda, por favor.

Comment: Usa `\( \)` alrededor de la fórmula en vez de `\[ \]`

Comment: No funciona. Puedes buscar otra solución?

Comment: El comentario de @abulafia es correcto y te ayudará a resolverlo, pero tienes muchos más problemas, pero en el HTML que estás usando, pues usas saltos de línea forzados `<br>`, párrafos que generan nuevas líneas `<p>`, cierres de elementos sin que estuvieran abiertos, en fin... el problema es tu HTML, además de lo indicado por abulafia. Como son varias cosas arréglalo tu mismo poniendo el código que has puesto en esta pregunta en https://jsfiddle.net y cuando lo peges fíjate en todo lo que te va a marcar en rojo. Lo arreglas y luego editas esta pregunta y lo pones bien, y te ayudamos mejor.

Comment: Además de resolver todos los problemas que comenta @masterguru, y de usar `\( \)` como dije en mi anterior comentario, obviamente tienes que quitar también el `<p>` que inicia un nuevo párrafo antes de la fórmula, así como el `<div>` que puede causar que se muestre en bloque aparte. Como esto ya eran temas de html y no de latex ni los mencioné (y ni me fijé en ellos). Mira en este [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yae14rhb/) como queda la cosa. Aún sin arreglar todos los errores (que siguen apareciendo en rojo), la fórmula ya sale en línea como querías.

Comment: vale entendido, lo corregí y ya no tengo problemas con el `\(\)` solo y únicamente si no utilizo el div, y si lo necesito por ejemplo, para modificar esa parte en css, pero no quiero que se vaya a otra línea diferente, ¿Cómo lo hago? Porque si utilizo div en una ecuación para cambiarla en CSS, se mueve a una nueva línea, y no quiero eso

Comment: Cambia el `div` por `span` y ya lo tienes.